# Custom locale for login label [devise]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So, I have custom view **sessions/new.html.haml**

I have a label in my form

```
    = f.label :login
```

How my **en.yml** should look like to replace **Login** with **Email or Username**

I included gem rails-i18n and tried

```
en:
   login: "Email or Username"
```

or

```
en:
   devise:
   sessions:
     new:
       login: Email or Username"
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Rails implements a convenient way to look up the locale inside views. When you have the following dictionary.

In locale folder.

```
locale
     en
       session
             new
               en.yml
```

In en.yml

```
en:
  sessions:
    new:
        login: "Email or Username"
```

In new.html.slim:

```
t.('.login')
```

This is I18n lazylookup

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do that.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: "User"
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Email"
        login: "Email or Username"
        password: "Password"
        password_confirmation: "Password confirmation"
        current_password: "Current password"
        remember_me: "Remember me"
```

And make sure your locale is 'en' not 'en-us'